# calling a function from a thread and letting the original thread run in the background

Tags: python, multithreading

I am calling a function from a thread and as soon as the function starts running both the threads stop working until the function has finished executing and after the function execution the program just stops.

```
class listen(threading.Thread):

    def __init__(self):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.playmusicobject = playmusic()
        self.objectspeak = speak()
        self.apiobject = googleAPI()

    def listening(self):

        self.r = sr.Recognizer()
        threadLock.acquire()
        try:

            with sr.Microphone() as source:
                print("say something")
                self.audio = self.r.listen(source)

        finally:
            threadLock.release()

    def checkingaudio(self):

        threadLock.acquire()
        try:
            # a = str(self.r.recognize_google(self.audio))
            a = str(self.r.recognize_google(self.audio))
            print(a)
            if a in greetings:
                self.objectspeak.speaking("I am good how are you?")

            if a in music:
                print("playing music")
                self.playmusicobject.play()

            if a in stop:
                print("stopping")
                self.playmusicobject.b()

            if a in api:
                self.apiobject.distance()
        finally:
            threadLock.release()

class playmusic:

    def play(self):
        playsound.playsound("playthisfile")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    while 1:
        d = listen()
        t1 = threading.Thread(target=d.listening)
        t1.start()
        t2 = threading.Thread(target=d.checkingaudio)
        t2.start()
```

whenever I call the play function in playmusic both the threads supposedly stop and after the play function's execution the program stops. Is there anyway that the function play or for the matter of fact any other function called by the thread running the function CheckingAudio, won't stop the 2 original threads.I tried running the play function as a thread of its own but was unsucessful in doing so, it just gave me an error that said unable to start thread t3, the way  was calling the function as a thread was (and this is probably wrong)

```
        if a in music:
            print("playing music")
            t3 = threading.Thread(target=self.playmusicobject.play)
            t3.start()
```

I tried creating a runplaythread function in playmusic class but still gave me the error cannot start the thread.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure it will fix your problem, but your last thread's target is wrong, you're using `self` instead of `d` to call your instance of `listen`.

This is your code **corrected to replace context**:

```python
    if a in music:
        print("playing music")
        t3 = threading.Thread(target=d.playmusicobject.play)
        t3.start()
```

NOTE: A comment would probably have been ok, but not enough rep.

EDIT: Reuse of OP's code for context is now explicitly mentioned. (Though that was obvious enough)

EDIT2: Where you are calling your third thread was not clear, but don't seems ok, see comments.

Comment: you literally took the code from my question and introduced it as an answer, and the reason why i am using `self.playmusicobject.play` is because play function is in a different class. NOTE: A down vote would probably be best but sorry not enough rep

Comment: As said in my answer, you're using `self` instead of you instance name `d` in your code. I corrected that and re-used your code for context. I also mentioned that I couldn't comment your answer and that it would have been better than a separate answer. I will edited so it is more explicit, but please pay attention to the details.

Comment: Moreover, I am not sure that starting a thread from within your class (if this is what you suggested) is a good idea, as you're using a `threadLock` in the first method.